# How do i change a character in a list with a key in another dictionary within Python?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, replace

I'm trying to make a function that checks the validity of an ID. The IDs start with A, B, C, or D. And I was having trouble replacing the A, B, C, Ds in the input from the user with the key values in the dictionary. Please Help Me~

For example, if the user inputs A, then the program shall check if A is in the dictionary and if it is then it will replace it with the value of the key, i.e. 10.

Thanks

```
ID_dict = {"A": 10, "B" : 11, "C" : 12, "D" : 13}

ID = list(raw_input("What is your ID"))

def check_id(ID):

???
```

Comment: Could you please provide a full example of your desired outcome. i.e., what does the user input and what is the resulting output? That will help us understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: could you be more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
ID_dict = {"A": 10, "B" : 11, "C" : 12, "D" : 13}

ID = raw_input("What is your ID")

def check_id(ID):
     if ID in ID_dict:
          print "Yes Valid"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
ID = list(raw_input("What is your ID"))
def check_id(ID):
    for a in ID:
        if a.upper() in ID_dict:
            print a.upper() +" is there"
        else:
            print a.upper()+" is not there"

check_id(ID)
```

**output:**

```
What is your IDasde
A is there
S is not there
D is there
E is not there
```